# How to prevent colors mixing on Android

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I have two Paint-objects. First(1) I use to draw semi-tranpsarent background, second(2) - for painting with finger. Everything is OK except one thing - color of (2) becomes darker when I finish drawing. I wish (1) not to affect on (2). I tried all xfermodes, but it didn't help. What I have to do to solve this issue?

Comment: I solved issue, it is so stupid - I just changed places of 2 lines:

insted of this:
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null); <<-1
canvas.drawPaint(mCanvasPaint);         <<-2 

i wrote this:
canvas.drawPaint(mCanvasPaint);         <<-2
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null); <<-1